# Correlation of multiple categorical variables

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

A hypothetical story: Harry is a happy chap living in a small village, however he has 1 small problem: he turns into a wolf sometimes. He only knows a little bit about statistics, and wants to find out what trigger the transformation, so he starts a diary documenting his daily activities and association with wolf tranformation.

Part of his diary details are:

```
| Date | Turn to wolf | swim | drink tea | see moon | touch tree | pat cat |
|------|--------------|------|-----------|----------|------------|---------|
|      | yes          | no   | no        | yes      | no         | no      |
|      | yes          | no   | yes       | yes      | no         | no      |
|      | no           | yes  | no        | yes      | yes        | yes     |
|      | no           | no   | yes       | no       | no         | yes     |
|      | yes          | yes  | yes       | yes      | yes        | no      |
|      | no           | no   | yes       | no       | yes        | yes     |
|      | no           | no   | no        | yes      | yes        | yes     |
```

He contemplated for a while, what would be the best approach to find the assocation between all the variables and transformation into a wolf.

One possible way is to create a 2x2 table and caluclate X2, or Phi for each pair of variables, repeat for all

```
|           | wolf: yes | wolf: no |
|-----------|-----------|----------|
| swim: yes | 1         | 1        |
| swim: no  | 2         | 3        |
```

The other way is to convert yes/no into 1/0 and try to find R2 (Pearson's is what he knows abt) between two variables

```
|   | wolf | swim |
|---|------|------|
|   | 1    | 0    |
|   | 1    | 0    |
|   | 0    | 1    |
|   | 0    | 0    |
|   | 1    | 1    |
|   | 0    | 0    |
|   | 0    | 0    |
```

He is sure there must be other more appropriate statitical tests, but he doesn't know what he doesn't know.

Just looking at the table, he suspects that seeing the moon and turning into a wolf has a high postive correlation, while patting a cat has a negative correlation. He just wants to be more statistically correct rather than following the gut feeling.

So the question is: what would be the appropriate tests to detect associations between turning into a wolf and a daily activity (or combinations of activities). He doesn't want to turn into a wolf permanantly.

Comment: possibly of interest: [Cramer's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r's_V).  The Pearson correlation coefficient for two binary variables is the same as the $\phi$ coefficient, where $\phi^2 = \chi^2/n$.  For variables of multiple dimensions, $V = \sqrt((\chi^2/n))/min(k-1, r-1))$ where $r$ and $k$ are the dimensions of the two variables.

Comment: Thanks Caffeine, does Cramer's V teases apart confounding variables?

Comment: It's just a measure of association you could use between turning into a wolf and any given daily activity.  If you were trying to consider all the daily activities at once, you might want to use regression and consider the odds ratio and confidence interval for each activity.  If you are worried about interactions, you can create terms for those in the model.

Comment: Logistic regression?